# Metro (Windows Store App) DateTime Format in XAML

Tags: winrt-xaml

I haf a DateTime Property.
This is Bound to a Textbox with

```
<TextBlock Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0" Text="{Binding StartDateString, Mode=TwoWay}" x:Name="date" />
```

In WPF it was possible to format the DateTime Output with the following syntax

```
<TextBlock Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0" Text="{Binding StartDateString, FormatString="dd.mm.yyyy" Mode=TwoWay}" x:Name="date" />
```

In the Metro Apps (winrt ... Windows Store Apps... how it is called now?), the FormatString property is not possible.

Is there another way to do the format in the xaml file?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You're right.  There isn't a `FormatString` parameter in WinRT.  You should probably use a value converter.  Here's a link to one that should do what you want:

http://blogs.u2u.be/diederik/post/2012/03/19/A-StringFormat-converter-for-Windows-8-Metro.aspx

Comment: Thank you very much. Is that the only way to do that?

Comment: It's the best way to do conversions in bindings.  WinRT doesn't have as much built in to XAML as WPF did, so sometimes you have to extend it a bit.